# How to Access Variable From One Class in Another Class? [C#]

Tags: c#, class, scope

So I am working on a C# program that takes in a set of delimited text files within a directory and parses out the info within the files (i.e. the file path, file name, associated keywords). And this is what a sample file looks like...

```
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image2.jpeg;image0;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image3.jpeg;image1;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image4.jpeg;image2;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4
C:\Documents and Settings\workspace\Extracted Items\image5.jpeg;image3;keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4
```

Well I was given some code by my partner that does this, but I need to be able to access the list variable, that is populated within one of the methods.  This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class FileIO
    {
        private static Boolean isTextFile;
        private static Boolean debug;

        private static int semiColonLoc1, semiColonLoc2, dblQuoteLoc1;
        private static int lineLength, currentTagLength;
        private static int numImages;
        private static int numFiles;
        public static List<Image> lImageSet;

        /*
          ****************************************************
          ***** CHANGE THIS PATH TO YOUR PROPERTIES FILE *****
          ****************************************************
        */
        private static readonly string propertiesFileDir = "C:/Documents and Settings/properties.properties";

        public PropertyKeys getProperties(string propertiesFileDir, PropertyKeys aPropertyKeys)
        {
            string line;
            string directoryKey = "extractedInfoDirectory";
            string debugKey = "debug2";
            string directory;

            Boolean isDirectoryKey;
            Boolean isDebugKey;

            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(propertiesFileDir);

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                isDirectoryKey = false;
                isDebugKey = false;

                //  If the current line is a certain length, checks the current line's key
                if (line.Length > debugKey.Length)
                {
                    isDebugKey = line.Substring(0, debugKey.Length).Equals(debugKey, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                    if (line.Length > directoryKey.Length)
                    {
                        isDirectoryKey = line.Substring(0, directoryKey.Length).Equals(directoryKey, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    }
                }

                //  Checks if the current line's key is the extractedInfoDirectory
                if (isDirectoryKey)
                {
                    directory = line.Substring(directoryKey.Length + 1);
                    aPropertyKeys.setExtractedInfoDir(directory);
                }

                //  Checks if the current line's key is the debug2
                else if (isDebugKey)
                {
                    debug = Convert.ToBoolean(line.Substring(debugKey.Length + 1));
                    aPropertyKeys.setDebug(debug);
                }
            }

            return aPropertyKeys;
        }

        public void loadFile()
        {

            string line;
            string tempLine;
            string fileToRead;
            string fileRename;
            string imagePath, imageName, imageTags, currentTag;
            string extractedInfoDir;
            string extension;
            string textfile = "txt";
            string[] filePaths;

            PropertyKeys aPropertyKeys = new PropertyKeys();

            //  Finds extractedInfoDir and debug values
            aPropertyKeys = getProperties(propertiesFileDir, aPropertyKeys);
            extractedInfoDir = aPropertyKeys.getExtractedInfoDir();
            debug = aPropertyKeys.getDebug();

            //  Finds all files in the extracted info directory
            filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(extractedInfoDir);
            numFiles = filePaths.Length;

            //  For each file in the directory...
            for (int n = 0; n < numFiles; n++)
            {
                int k = filePaths[n].Length;

                // Finds extension for the current file
                extension = filePaths[n].Substring(k - 3);

                // Checks if the current file is .txt
                isTextFile = extension.Equals(textfile, StringComparison.Ordinal);

                // Only reads file if it is .txt
                if (isTextFile == true)
                {

                    fileToRead = filePaths[n];
                    Console.WriteLine(fileToRead);
                    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToRead);

                    //  Reset variables and create a new lImageSet object
                    lImageSet = new List<Image>();

                    line = ""; tempLine = ""; imagePath = ""; imageName = ""; imageTags = ""; currentTag = "";
                    semiColonLoc1 = 0; semiColonLoc2 = 0; dblQuoteLoc1 = 0; lineLength = 0; currentTagLength = 0; numImages = 0;

                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        //  Creates a new Image object
                        Image image = new Image();
                        numImages++;

                        lineLength = line.Length;

                        //  Finds the image path (first semicolon delimited field)
                        semiColonLoc1 = line.IndexOf(";");
                        imagePath = line.Substring(0, semiColonLoc1);
                        image.setPath(imagePath);

                        tempLine = line.Substring(semiColonLoc1 + 1);

                        //  Finds the image name (second semicolon delimited field)
                        semiColonLoc2 = tempLine.IndexOf(";");
                        imageName = tempLine.Substring(0, semiColonLoc2);
                        image.setName(imageName);

                        tempLine = tempLine.Substring(semiColonLoc2 + 1);

                        //  Finds the image tags (third semicolon delimited field)
                        imageTags = tempLine;

                        dblQuoteLoc1 = 0;

                        // Continues to gather tags until there are none left
                        while (dblQuoteLoc1 != -1)
                        {
                            dblQuoteLoc1 = imageTags.IndexOf("\"");
                            imageTags = imageTags.Substring(dblQuoteLoc1 + 1);
                            dblQuoteLoc1 = imageTags.IndexOf("\"");

                            if (dblQuoteLoc1 != -1)
                            {
                                //  Finds the next image tag (double quote deliminated)
                                currentTag = imageTags.Substring(0, dblQuoteLoc1);
                                currentTagLength = currentTag.Length;

                                //  Adds the tag to the current image
                                image.addTag(currentTag);
                                image.iNumTags++;
                                imageTags = imageTags.Substring(dblQuoteLoc1 + 1);
                            }
                        }

                        //  Adds the image to the current image set
                        lImageSet.Add(image);

                    }

                    //  Prints out information about what information has been stored
                    if (debug == true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Finished file " + (n + 1) + ": " + filePaths[n]);

                        for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("***Image " + (i + 1) + "***");
                            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + lImageSet.ElementAt(i).getName());
                            Console.WriteLine("Path: " + lImageSet.ElementAt(i).getPath());
                            Console.WriteLine("Tags: ");

                            for (int j = 0; j < lImageSet.ElementAt(i).iNumTags; j++)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(lImageSet.ElementAt(i).lTags.ElementAt(j));
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    file.Close();

                    //  Changes destination file extension to .tmp
                    fileRename = fileToRead.Substring(0, fileToRead.Length - 4);
                    fileRename += ".tmp";

                    //  Changes file extension to .tmp
                    System.IO.File.Move(fileToRead, fileRename);
                }

                //  Not a text file
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Skipping file (no .txt extension)");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't want to mess with his code too much as he is not here for the time being to fix anything. So I just want to know how to access `lImageSet` from within his code in another class of mine. I was hoping it would be something like instantiating FileIO with `FileIO fo = new FileIO`, then doing something like `fo.loadFile().lImageSet` but that's not the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are all members static ?  What if you have multiple instances of that class ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's public -- so from your class, you can just access it as:

```
FileIO.lImageSet
```

To get to the values in it, just iterate over it as:

```
//from FishBasketGordo's answer - load up the fo object
FileIO fo = new FileIO();
fo.loadFile();

foreach(var img in FileIO.lImageSet) {
  //do something with each img item in lImageSet here...
}
```

**EDIT**: I built upon FishBasketGordo's answer by incorporating his `loadFile()` call into my sample.

Comment: So in the foreach loop, if you notice how in the code posted in the OP towards the bottom he has `Console.WriteLine("Name: " + lImageSet.ElementAt(i).getName());` , I cannot access the "ElementAt" method, so how do I get to the position I want in the list?

Comment: Nvm, I was able to figure it out. Thank you as well as everyone else for your help! I'll give you the answer since you went the extra mile and added the foreach in there. :)

Answer (score 3):

Since lImageSet is static, all you need to do to access it is:

`List<image> theList = FileIO.lImageSet;`

No instantiated object is necessary to get a reference to that field.

Answer (score 2):

The list is static, so you access it with the *name* of the class:

```
List<Image> theList = FileIO.lImageSet
```

Answer (score 2):

The `loadFile` method returns `void`, so you cannot use the dot operator to access anything from it. You'll want to do something like this:

```
FileIO fo = new FileIO();
fo.loadFile();
List<Image> theImages = FileIO.lImageSet;
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me that I didn't put the loading of the FileIO obj.

Answer (score 1):

Because `lImageSet` is `static`, so you don't need to instantiate FileIO to get it.

Try `FileIO.lImageSet`